# how to setup log4j configuration file

Tags: java, apache, logging

I have just started using the log4j 
if i have the below log4j properties file , what should i modify in the below code to make a file 
log.out for the application "test-war" deployed in apache tomcat 7.0.

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${catalina-base}/logs/log.out

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

Comment: try changing this line `log4j.appender.FILE.File=${catalina-base}/logs/log.out`

Comment: this looks like its already configured to produce a file called log.out. have you tried searching your system for that file? maybe ${catalina-base} leads to some place other than you think?

Comment: i have somewhat changed my war and named it as log-example

and changed my properties file also now it creates the file test.log

but the file is empty nothing is written in the file


i am using jsp and the code i have used to print the log message is 

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("step1.jsp");
 logger.info("ths is test");

Comment: My log file now creates the file with the date but the format of the file is of type file not .txt. will you please help me in this

Answer (score 0):

you config file is good, I think the problem is your jsp, that did you import the class that used, and also I recomment you to use xml config of log4j

Comment: yes i have imported the class

and it the logs are working fine now thanks to all

Comment: pal, choose an answer, so that the other people can find it.

Answer (score 0):

This log4j property snippet will generate log file in tomcat log directory and save the log files in log.out.xxx-yy-mm format , this will help you to manipulate the log files easily.

```
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE=${catalina.base}/logs/log.out
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
```

Comment: hi rahul ,

could you please tell me how to embed the date at the end of my log file that i.e for example the file name to be comes like

log.2013-01-09

Comment: Above code(Log4J property) will automatically save the previous day's log files to .log.xxx-mm-dd format.

Comment: i am using the below log file to produre a log file with date at the end ,can you please tell me what wrong i am doing
it produces the file but not with the date at the end
log4j.rootLogger=info,myapplication
log4j.appender.myapplication=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myapplication.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.myapplication.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.myapplication.File=${catalina.base}/logs/testlogs/test.log
log4j.appender.myapplication.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.logger=info,myapplication